# Custom post type archive and single.php files not working

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

Hi I've created a custom post type called shows.

here is the code for it.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'show_register');

function show_register() {
        //arguments to create the post type.
        $args = array(
                'label' => __('shows'),
                'singular_label' => __('Show'),
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'shows', 'with_front'
                => false), );
                //Register type and custom taxonomy for type.
                register_post_type( 'shows' , $args );

                register_taxonomy("Show-type", array("shows"),
                array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Show
                Types", "singular_label" => "Show Type", "rewrite"
                => true, "slug" => 'show-type'));
}
?>
```

I've created 2 files that follow accordingly to the wordpress hierarchy and called them `archive-shows.php` and `single-shows.php`. These should automatically link to the correct pages however for some reason they both default back to index.php.

The normal `single.php` and `archive.php` work as normal.

Fix's tried Permalinks Flushed has `archive = true`

please any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe your templates should be using the slug you registered for the post type? eg. `show-type`.

Comment: Isn't that the taxonomy type?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake.. glanced over that way too fast.

Comment: still got no fix at all

Comment: Browser cache issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flush your permalinks after you register these things. There are ways to do that automatically but the quick and dirty way is to browse to `wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks` and click "Save Changes". That will work fine if this is your site and you aren't distributing a plugin. If this is a plugin (which it probably should be), you can run [`flush_rewrite_rules();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) on the plugin's activation hook. An example of doing that from the Codex:

```
function myplugin_activate() {
    // register taxonomies/post types here
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );
```

Other than that, I did not have any issue with your code (copied un-altered). The CPT registered and both `single-shows.php` and `archive-shows.php` worked after flushing the permalinks.

Comment: did this answer your question, @Dannyw24 ?