# Template with Custom Post Type (Custom Tables) does not work

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I'm using a Custom Post Type (CPT) `my-project` stored in a custom table MY_PROJECT.

Here is the CPT registering code:

```
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Projects ' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Project' ),
                    // other labels
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( 'Projects Management' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 100,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'project', 'with_front' => false ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'my-project', $args );
```

As you can see I don't use any fields from Wordpress (`'supports' => false,`) as I'm using my own fields and insert them in my custom table; but I set `post-name` and `post-title` in `wp_posts` table when creating a new CPT `my-project`.

I want to display all my fields using basic template twentyeleven, I found that I have to add this code in `themes/twentyeleven/functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'my-project' ) );
return $query;
}
```

=> First question: is there another way to register my CPT to display it/ is that the best place to write this?

Then I created 2 files in `themes/twentyeleven/`:

1 `archive-my-project.php` (should display list of `my-project`)

2 `single-my-project.php` (should display one `my-project`)

=> Second question, using "Preview before modification" button in admin will display a list of all my CPT `my-project` (only the title). It should be only one project, and wordpress should use `single-my-project.php` file right? The URL is ok: `http://localhost/wordpress/project/project1/`. And clicking on one of the title will display "Nothing found" page... I tried to edit`single-my-project.php` content to display "TEST" string but nothing changed...

=> Third question: slug (which I set to `project`) is used only in the URL and nowhere else, is that right? Nothing to do with file names `single-my-project.php` (ok) / `single-project.php` (not ok)?

Please note I've read about [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Thanks for your help,

Xavier

Comment: A custom ***table***?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99014/21376

Comment: Please ask only *one* question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1: I don't really understand this question, but what you have done looks alright. I might add the `pre_get_posts` filter in the same place as register the post type-- presumably a plugin file-- but registering in the theme should work. It won't transfer to another theme if you do that though.

Question #2: You have to flush the permalinks when you register a new CPT. There are a number of questions and answers here concerning that. Recently, I answered this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99014/21376 The short version of the story is "Go to wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks and click the save button".

Qustions #3: The file names come from the name (slug) you use to register to post type-- the first parameter here: `register_post_type( 'my-project', $args );`. The other arguments do not effect that, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't know about the flush process, it doesnt work for me but it's ok when doing "Go to wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks and click the save button". I'll try to sort this out. It still using the templates/twentyeleven/index.php file instead of single-my-project.php or archive-my-project.php files, don't know why. I'll come back later if I can find any solution in the process. Thank you.