# Archive page for custom post type not working

Tags: custom-post-types, single, custom-post-type-archives

I use a plugin called CPT-onomies to create Custom Post Types. I created a post type called "case", and set "Has Archive Page" to true, but when i try to view a single case, i just get 404'd. Same thing also happens if i try to view the actual archive, eg. "site.com/case" and not "site.com/case/case-item".

Here's a screenshot of my settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOoB1.png

I've tried disabling/enablind it, no success. I also tried changing permalink structure of the whole site (from settings -> permalinks) because sometimes that doesn't update.

Have i missed something in the settings or is this a bug in the plugin? I've gone through it several times and i can't find anything that would prevent it from working.

I have a template file called `single.php` that should be used. I also tried `single-case.php` but that didn't make any difference.

## Solution

I found a solution here: http://gabrieleromanato.name/wordpress-fix-the-404-error-on-custom-post-types/

Comment: I have this similar problem before, and it was resolved 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99538/post-type-archive-page-not-working

Comment: I tried manually setting the rewrite as you suggested, but that didn't work either (refreshed permalinks between). It should also not be needed because the plugin has it's own defaults. Have you looked at the screenshot? I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: I checked your screenshot, try setting hierarchical to true. I am not familiar with CPT-onomies, but if you don't mind I  I suggest you to switch to [custom-post-type-ui](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

Comment: Still no luck after setting hierarchical to true. :/ This is my first time using the plugin, i just grabbed one of the top ones. I'll make sure to try another one next time, but i'm afraid i'm stuck with it for now (i've already added tons of content, if i remove the post types i can say goodbye to the content as well).

Comment: If your plugin provides a registration code of your post type, it would be better if you will include it in your post.
and make sure you have the following:
 
`archive-{post-type.php}` - is for displaying the list of your post under your custom post type
 
`taxonomy-{taxonomy-name.php}` is for displaying the list of your posts that belongs to your particular taxonomy name

and  `single-{post-type.php}` - for displaying single post of your particular custom post type.

Comment: The registration code is "trailers" (assuming i understood you correctly - the "code" is the name you use to reference the post type, right?). I don't care about the archive itself, i only need to display individual posts (i link to the post from somewhere else), and i do indeed have a `single-trailers.php` template available. I also have `page.php` which it falls back to, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I would just dump the plugin and register it myself via [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), it's pretty trivial and removes the mystery of what some plugin is doing behind the scenes. If you use the same name to register your post type, all your content will be accessible, removing a registered post type doesn't touch the data in the database.

Comment: I actually have a feeling removing the post type will also remove all the posts within. That's up to the plugin to decide, and if it were to keep all the posts that would clutter the database, right? I don't know, i'll back everything up and give it a shot. I'll report back within a few hours! For the record i used to add it manually before, but i decided to switch it up and try something new. That was a bad idea ~ "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: you can look in the plugin's uninstall.php file, I doubt it touches the posts.

Comment: You were indeed right! I'll stick to doing it manually, thanks!

Comment: Yea i'm actually still having problems with it, the archive still doesn't show up. Here are the arguments i pass to the post type: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Q8su2E1z See anything weird in there?

Comment: Do you have any other content in your site that might have a conflicting URL? Any pages with a slug/page name of 'case'?

Comment: @RachelCarden I sent you a reply at [http://wordpress.org/support/...](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/archive-page-with-your-plugin?replies=4#post-4231357)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and select it as the correct answer, so your question doesn't sit in the tomb of unanswered questions

Comment: @MatthewBoynes Good point. Done!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution here:
http://gabrieleromanato.name/wordpress-fix-the-404-error-on-custom-post-types/

Here's what you need to do to get it to work (quoted from site above):

1. Go to Settings → Permalinks and change your current structure to:
   /%category%/%postname%
2. Save changes.
3. Restore your original permalink settings. Save changes.

Comment: This trick just worked for me as well... strange but true.

Comment: This worked for me. ugh after an hour looking into why it wasn't working.

Comment: That structure was actually my original structure -_-